# Scheduling of tasks with the Android JobScheduler that require network access

Tags: android, service, job-scheduling

In my android application i want to update the foreign currency exchange rate in each day when the network is there.I want to update the currency rate only once in each day and repeat the process in next days.Recently I heard about android job scheduler.Is it good to use for my problem? If so how can i use that to update the exchange rate in each day? Please help me.Also what to do in android versions below lollipop?

Comment: you can use AlaramManager to do this. I have same functionality in my app and it is working perfect.

Comment: @Divyesh can u show me some codes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method start alaram manger at 15:30 every day. add this in your mainActivity:

```
private void setNotifyAlarm() {
        long _alarm;
        AlarmManager al;
        PendingIntent fintent;
        Intent notif;

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar wakeupcall = Calendar.getInstance();
        wakeupcall.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        wakeupcall.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        wakeupcall.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        if (wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
            _alarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY+1);
        else
            _alarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis();


        al = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        notif= new Intent(this,TestNotifyService.class);
        fintent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,notif,0);

        if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            al.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm, fintent);
            Log.d("lowerMN","hahah");
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT  && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            al.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm,fintent);
            Log.d("kitkatMN","hahah");
        }
        else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            al.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm,fintent);
            Log.d("marshmallowMN","hahah");
        }

    }
```

Now, In TestNotifyService.java class that actually do your work,

```
public class TestNotifyService extends IntentService {

    PowerManager powerManager;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock=null;
    private AlarmManager al;
    PendingIntent fintent;
    Intent notif;
    final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    long _alarm;

    public TestNotifyService() {
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "TRYNOTIFY");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        fetchingDATA();
    }

    private void fetchingDATA() {
        try {

            ........CALL WEBSERVICE TO GET LATEST DATA.......

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        reSETNOTIFY();
        wakeLock.release();
    }

    private void reSETNOTIFY() {

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar wakeupcall = Calendar.getInstance();
        wakeupcall.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        wakeupcall.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        wakeupcall.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        if (wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
            _alarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY+1)+25000;
        else
            _alarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis()+25000;

        al = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        notif= new Intent(this,TestNotifyService.class);
        fintent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,notif,0);

        if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            al.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm, fintent);
            Log.d("lowerNS","hahah");
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT  && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            al.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm,fintent);
            Log.d("kitkatNS","hahah");
        }
        else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            al.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm,fintent);
            Log.d("marshmallowNS","hahah");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Now, when device restarted you need to reset Alarm using Brodcast Receiver:

```
public class Nauto extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    public Nauto() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long _Nalarm;
        Log.d("Bootcompleted","starting");
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){

            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, TestNotifyService.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent1, 0);

            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar wakeupcall = Calendar.getInstance();
            wakeupcall.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            wakeupcall.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
            wakeupcall.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

            if (wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
                _Nalarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY+1);
            else
                _Nalarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis();

            if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_Nalarm, alarmIntent);
                Log.d("lowerNB","hahah");
            }
            else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT  && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_Nalarm,alarmIntent);
                Log.d("kitkatNB","hahah");
            }
            else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_Nalarm,alarmIntent);
                Log.d("marshmallowNB","hahah");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

At last, add this in Manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".Nauto" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<service android:name=".TestNotifyService" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Let me know if it working or not.

Comment: what will do this service if there is no network connection at time 15:30 ??

Comment: it wait for network, in my case when i switch on network after 15:30 app do its work after 20-15 minute.

Comment: How can i eliminate that 15-20 minute delay??

Comment: no, i mean when on network after 20 mins, it still runs that time

Comment: If i didn't have a network access on this day and if i switch on the network on nxt day at 15.30 or later does it fire two service including the previous day service??

Comment: Also does this service work even if i didn't open my app on that day??

Comment: Yes it run on another thread. You just need to save data from server to Sqlite Database.

Comment: Do you know how to use Android JobScheduler for my problem in versions above lollipop.For below versions i think ur method of using alarm manager is good.

Comment: I am currently using 5.2.1

Comment: Does i need to call the setNotifyAlarm() in mainactivity oncreate??

Comment: Yes.  Everytime app starts this method called.   If want, you can call this method in first time when app installs.

Comment: How that possible??

Comment: In your mainactivity, use sharedpreference to save some int value. When app opens make that int 1 and save. After again when app is open check for that value, if value is 1 then igonere and if 0 then call setNotifyAlarm() mdthod.

Comment: how to get the context of MainActivity in TestNotifyService??

Comment: What u mean mainactivity context? What u wanr to do

Comment: I want to call my DBHelper calss in TestNotifyService, It requires the activity context.

Comment: Ok now i understood Intent Service is a context , so i can use this as context there

Comment: Thats right. First i used db in service class with use of getBaseContext

Comment: How can i make the same process to execute in every 6 hours??

Comment: Change _alarm to 6*3600000 so that run every 6 hour.

Comment: Ok, but where to set this?

Comment: Above code, every _alarm and _Nalarm variable used to set alaram manager changed to 6*3600000.

Comment: Is it like this. _Nalarm=6*3600000 ? If so is there any need to set the wakeupcall ?

Comment: u can delete wakeupcall and just use 6*3600000 for setting alarm

Comment: If i do so then when will be the first api call occurs ? is it imediatly after calling the setNotifyAlarm() method or 6 hour after the setNotifyAlarm() call?

Comment: i think it should fire 6 hour after calling metod, but u can make sure by it using log in metod.chec wen it fire.

Comment: How can i stop this service if i want to stop it?

Comment: By using stopSelf();. But intent service automatically stop when onHandleIntent() is completed.

Comment: But when does this onHandleIntent() is completed??Also if the user force stop the app then does that stop the service also??

Comment: When app is force stops all services stops. OnHandleIntent is completed when your code inside that method done executing.